# C# Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Error Setting Range .Formula to Range .Value2

Tags: c#, excel-formula, excel-interop, comexception

I have C# code writing to Excel.  The following code works:

```
var probForExcel = new string[profileSize, 1];

Range range3 = worksheet.Range["C5", "C" + (startRow + profileSize - 1)];

range3.Value = probForExcel;

range3.NumberFormat = "0.00000000000E+0";

range3.Formula = range3.Value2; //NEEDED FOR ACTUAL FORMULAS otherwise writes in xls as string
```

Now I am trying to use a List of Type Range:

```
 var formulaForExcel = new List<string[,]>();
            var formularange1 = new List<Range>();

            for (var i = 0; i < profileSize; i++)
            {
                var count = formulas[i].Count();
                formularange1.Add(worksheet.Range[worksheet.Cells[rowTracker, 2], worksheet.Cells[rowTracker, count]]);
                formulaForExcel.Add(new string[1, count]);
                var j = 0;
                foreach (var formula in formulas[i])
                {
                    formulaForExcel[i][0, j] = formula;
                    j++;
                }

                formularange1[i].Value = formulaForExcel[i];
                formularange1[i].Formula = formularange1[i].Value2;//CRASHES HERE
                rowTracker++;
            }
```

The program runs without the following line of code:

```
formularange1[i].Formula = formularange1[i].Value2;//CRASHES HERE
```

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC'

But it prints the formula as a string without that line of code and I have to go into each cell and hit enter for it to evaluate as a formula.
Why does the syntax work, no compile errors. And it runs in the first part of the code, where it's not in a list.  I put Range in a list and it crashes.
Unsure if the .Formula is causing the crash or the .Value2.

I get the same error if I do this

```
Range temp = formularange1[i];

temp.Formula = temp.Value2; //CRASHES HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

Found another post about Excel that helped me find my bug.  Because my excel formulas were automatically being built and very large, I didn't realize some of my formulas ended in a + sign.  Because I was adding things and checking length, some ended in +.
So I was doing a find and replace "=" with "=" and that would cause all the formulas to evaluate.  Except for the ones with a + at the end, excel threw an error.  Once I found this and updated my formula builder, now this works:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < profileSize; i++)
        {
            var count = formulas[i].Count();

            sumrangeForExcel[i, 0] = "=sum(C" + rowTracker + ":c"     + rowTracker + ")";

            formularange1.Add(worksheet.Range[worksheet.Cells[rowTracker, 3], worksheet.Cells[rowTracker,3+ count-1]]);
            formulaForExcel.Add(new string[1, count]);
            var j = 0;
            foreach (var formula in formulas[i])
            {
                formulaForExcel[i][0, j] = formula;
                //formularange1[i][0, j].Formula = formularange1[i][0, j].Value2; Erased my formulas
                j++;
            }

            formularange1[i].Value = formulaForExcel[i];
            formularange1[i].Formula = formularange1[i].Value2;//NO CRASHING

            formularange1[i].NumberFormat = "###,###,##0";
            rowTracker++;
        }
```

So, using interop is not easy and does not have the best error checking.  The error I had was unrelated to my actual problem.